# error in processmaker login page after installation

Tags: processmaker

I installed processmaker 3.5.7 on debian stable and there is an error in login page after installtion :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, null given, called in /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php on line 62 and defined in /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php:120 Stack trace: #0 /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php(62): Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator->__construct(Object(Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection), NULL, NULL) #1 /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(776): Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(App\Foundation\Application), Array) #2 /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(658): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure)) #3 /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(609): Il in /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php on line 120

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, null given, called in /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php on line 62 and defined in /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php:120 Stack trace: #0 /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php(62): Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator->__construct(Object(Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection), NULL, NULL) #1 /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(776): Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(App\Foundation\Application), Array) #2 /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(658): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure)) #3 /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(609): Il in /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php on line 120
```

apache2 2.4.38
php 7.3
mariadb 10.3.27

processmaker logs :

```
<400> Apr 27 01:33:12 production ERROR: Call to undefined method Monolog\Logger::singleton() {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to undefined method Monolog\\Logger::singleton() at /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Logger.php:273)"}
<400> Apr 27 01:33:12 production ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, null given, called in /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php on line 62 and defined in /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php:120
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php(62): Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator->__construct(Object(Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection), NULL, NULL)
#1 /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(776): Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(App\Foundation\Application), Array)
#2 /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(658): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#3 /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(609): Il {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 1): Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\\Routing\\UrlGenerator::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\\Http\\Request, null given, called in /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php on line 62 and defined in /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php:120\nStack trace:\n#0 /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php(62): Illuminate\\Routing\\UrlGenerator->__construct(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection), NULL, NULL)\n#1 /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(776): Illuminate\\Routing\\RoutingServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(App\\Foundation\\Application), Array)\n#2 /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(658): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build(Object(Closure))\n#3 /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(609): Il at /opt/processmaker/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php:120)"}
```

Comment: I've same problems.

Answer (score -2):

To make better use of ProcessMaker, it is better to use the Windows version as well
this is what you said about your simulator